# In spontaneous symmetry breaking, can we define quanta of $\phi$ field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, symmetry-breaking

A simple Lagrangian where spontaneous symmetry breaking is possible is that of a real scalar field $\phi$ with quartic interaction
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{\mu^2}{2}\phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4}\phi^4$$ and $\mu^2<0$. We say that spontaneous symmetry breaking signals a nonzero VEV $$\langle \Omega|\hat{\phi}|\Omega\rangle=v\neq 0$$ of the quantum field $\hat{\phi}$.

> - In this Lagrangian, can we declare $\phi$ to be a quantum field and replace it by $\hat{\phi}$?
> - If yes, how will you define the quanta of $\hat{\phi}$-field? How will you define its creation and annihilation operators? $|\Omega\rangle$ does not seem to be the vacuum from which quanta of $\phi$ field can be created/defined.

**Note 1** To be absolutely clear let me emphasize that I'm aware of the usual technique of redefining the field $\hat{\phi}$ by subtracting out the VEV $\hat{h}\equiv\hat{\phi}-v$ so that $\langle \Omega|\hat{h}|\Omega\rangle=0.$ Then quanta of $h$-field can be defined by $\hat{h}^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$. The question is not about this.

**Note 2** When I said

> *"In this Lagrangian, can we declare $\phi$ to be a quantum field and replace it by $\hat{\phi}$ ?"*

I didn't mean to ask if I can plug $\hat{\phi}$ in place of $\phi$ in $\mathcal{L}$. Sorry for the confusing language. I wanted to ask if we can quantize this theory without changing $\phi$ to $h$ i.e. do everything with $\phi$. I know that we can quantize $\phi^4$ theory. But with $\mu^2<0$, it's no longer a replica of the standard $\phi^4$ theory.

Answer (score 5):

> In this Lagrangian, can we declare $\phi$ to be a quantum field and replace it by $\hat{\phi}$?

Yes, absolutely. You can quantize any field you want, whether it's $\phi$, $\phi - v$, $\phi - 2v$, and so on.

> If yes, how will you define the quanta of $\hat{\phi}$-field? How will you define its creation and annihilation operators? $|\Omega\rangle$ does not seem to be the vacuum of from which quanta of $\phi$ field can be created/defined.

Recall that this entire machinery works for *free* field theories. In order to get it to work in general, we use interaction picture, where the field operators are treated as free. In this context, the quantization of $\phi$ runs in exactly the same way as for a typical, free massive scalar field.

The only difference is in the *state*. Because the vev of $\hat{\phi}$ isn't zero, there are a very large number of $\phi$ excitations present (as defined through the previous paragraph), in the zero-momentum (spatially uniform) mode. So if you wanted to compute anything, such as the scattering cross section of two $\phi$ excitations with nonzero momentum, it would get very complicated because you would have to account for the possibility of these excitations interacting with the many $\phi$ particles already there.

That's the point of defining the field $\hat{h} = \hat{\phi} - v$. In the vacuum, there aren't any $\hat{h}$ particles present, so you don't get this problem.

> Can you elaborate this a bit?

Note that the annihilation operator for the spatially uniform mode associated with the $\hat{h}$ field annihilates the vacuum. Therefore, the annihilation operator for the spatially uniform mode associated with the $\hat{\phi}$ field multiplies the vacuum by $v$. This is the definition of a coherent state, so there are a lot of $\hat{\phi}$-particles, but the number isn't determinate. (Of course, this is not very rigorous, because it's all in the naive interaction picture formalism.)

Comment: _"Because the vev of $\hat{\phi}$  isn't zero, there are a very large number of $\phi$ excitations present (as defined through the previous paragraph), in the zero-momentum (spatially uniform) mode."_ Can you elaborate this a bit? I think that $|\Omega\rangle$ is not a number eigenstate of $\hat{\phi}$ but that of $\hat{h}$ with zero $h$-type particles. I am not sure though.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Sure, added!

Comment: _"we use interaction picture, where the field operators are treated as free."_ Is this true? Aren't the fields are free only at $t\to \pm \infty$?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 In the usual "adiabatic turn-off" picture, the Heisenberg picture fields at free only at $t \to \pm \infty$. But the interaction picture fields are always free no matter what, because that's just the definition of interaction picture.

Comment: In the $\phi^4$ theory, the Heisenberg picture field $\phi_H$ cannot be expanded in creation and annihilation operators as $\phi_H\sim a+a^\dagger$. That I understand. Are you saying that the interaction picture field $\phi_I$ can be expanded as $\phi_I\sim a+a^\dagger$?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Yes, by the definition of interaction picture.